# Login to website which requires Cookies using c#

Tags: c#, webrequest, login-script

I'm trying to write a script in c# capable to retrieve some information from a website. These information are protected so I need to login before I can read them. That's what I think should be my procedure:

- First of all use a POST request to login into the website. Here my first problem: the page where I find the login form is this https://idp.kk-abcdefg.com/idp/Authn/UserPassword . Should I submit the POST request to this page or should I use a different address?

I've tested the headers using some tools of Firefox or Chrome but I can't understand which is the right procedure. I have noticed that If I open this login page I receive some cookies. If I delete these cookies and try to login by inserting user and password (via browser) I get an error as a response from the website .. it says that I need to activate cookies to be able to login. So it seems like when I open the login page for the first time I receive some cookies and then I need to send them together with the first POST request for login. Does it make sense for any of you?

That's the code I'm using right now:

```
        string formUrl = "https://idp.kk-abcdefg.de/idp/Authn/UserPassword";
        string formParams = string.Format("j_username=MyUserName&j_password=MyPassword”);
        string cookieHeader;
        string pageSource;
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

And I believe this is working because the result of pageSource changes if I use correct user / pass or I write them wrong. But when user / pass are correct, I'm still not able to login because I get the following error message: "This application requires cookies. Please make sure cookies are enabled in the settings of your browser. Please reload the login page and try logging in again".

This is the same error that I get if I disable cookies in my browser or if I delete cookies that I get when I load the login page for the first time.

Can you help me with all that? My idea is that I need to save the cookies received when I open the login page for the first time and then send them together with following requests but I don't know how to do ..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried to use Fiddler to see what cookies are set on requests after the login? That way you can replicate the same behavior. I see you are getting cookies but probably not setting them anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Web Application, once the user is logged in successfully a cookie is sent back to the browser to track the user session and to determine if the user is logged in or not during further requests. Furthermore login process of your application requires cookies to be sent from client along with username and password. So when you are trying to perform login without browser it complains about missing cookies.

If you know what cookies and their values need to be sent along with username and password for login, you can send them using cookieContainer in WebRequest as following.

```
string formUrl = "https://idp.kk-abcdefg.de/idp/Authn/UserPassword";
string formParams = string.Format("j_username=MyUserName&j_password=MyPassword");

string cookieHeader;
string pageSource;

CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
Cookie cookie1 = new Cookie("<<cookiename>>", "<<cookievalue>>","/", "<<yourdomainname>>");
Cookie cookie2 = new Cookie("<<cookiename>>", "<<cookievalue>>", "/", "<<yourdomainname>>");
cookieContainer.Add(cookie1);
cookieContainer.Add(cookie2);

// You can keep adding all required cookies this way.
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Method = "POST";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];

// You can access the cookies coming as part of response as following.
HttpWebResponse response = resp as HttpWebResponse;
if(response != null)
{
    var cookiesCollections = response.Cookies;
}

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
{
    pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

If you don't know the cookies and you need to get the cookies first by requesting login page before posting username and password then use following.

```
var loginPageUrl = "<<Your Login Page url>>";
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginPageUrl);
req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
req.Method = "GET";

WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

HttpWebResponse response = resp as HttpWebResponse;

CookieCollection cookies;
if (response != null)
{
    cookies = response.Cookies; //Use this cookies in above code to send with username and password.
}
```

Comment: Chetan, thanks a lot! Your explanation clarified me a lot of things. Unfortunately it's still not working. I tried the second approach: I first use a GET to visit the login page and take the cookies. Then I use the POST with user/pass and also CookieContainer.add(cookies), where cookies = response.Cookies from the GET. The problem is that now my "cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"]; " is a null, so I don't get anything back .. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't need to use response header for the cookies. Use the same approach as you use to retrieve cookies from the get call.

Comment: Even by using the same approach used for GET I don't get anything back after my POST .. By inspection with firefox I noticed that I get 2 different cookies before I'm logged in and 2 more (4 in total) after login. The two more are of type _pk_ref and _pk_ses, so they are Piwik cookies. Do you think that could be the reason why I can't log in? Thanks!

Comment: This website I need to login is using Shibboleth Single Sign-On (SSO) .. does it make things more difficult?

Comment: When you perform login from berowser, aftrr you enter username and password does it simply return the next page with cookies or does it perform any redirection and then return the final page with cookie? Is possible to share the url of login page which I can use to recreate the scenario.

Comment: What's your actual requirement? Did you consider using selenium web driver to perform such activities?

Comment: Thanks a lot Chetan! The complete address is the following: https://idp.hs-esslingen.de/idp/Authn/UserPassword . Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if my observation is correct but I tried using the URL and trace the request with Fiddler. When browsed this URL in browser it send back only one cookie "JSESSIONID" and in POST request the same cookie sent back. I replicated the same using code and I was able to retrieve the cookies from GET response and send the same cookie to POST request. Since I am not using the correct username and password it did not return any cookie in the response.

Answer (score -1):

You send the request login twice and **use single CookieContainer object**!